# Why doesn't my managed object see the other managed objects that are in a to many relationship to it?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Why doesn't my managed object "page" see the other managed objects "views" that are in a to many relationship to it? How do I get all the views that are associated with page by relationship, and access their properties (attributes)?

```
Page *page = (Page*)fetchedPages[indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"page's name is %@", page.name); //this works
NSLog(@"Page's views count %d", page.views.count); //this returns 0
```

I have fetched a managed object from core data. This object "page" is an instance of a subclass, called Page created from the entity description. I want to access properties of all objects that are in a to many relationship with page. I have another entity called View, which has a to one relationship to page. Page should have several "views", as they have been created, but when I try to log the views I get NULL or a count of 0. Do I need to do a separate fetch for these subViews of page?

Comment: `page.views` or `[page.views count]` should just work. Are you sure that you have associated views to that page?

Answer (score 0):

In a recent application I wrote I noticed that the setter for my relationship was not working and I had to write my own implementation based on another S.O. answer. Try adding the custom setter to your model and see if it works.

```
-(void)add{objectName}Object:({ObjectName} *)value{
    NSMutableSet* tempSet = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:self.{objectName}];

    [tempSet addObject:value];
    self.{objectName} = tempSet;
}
```